# wordpress how to force redirection from all pages to home

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a one-page wordpress site. It uses pages and posts but is all programatically included in the core template. I don't want users to ever accidentally access a single posts (even though it's unlikely that would ever happen). I would prefer to not have to use a 404 template either so it would be great to redirect EVERY page to the home page. Is this easily done without interfering with the default .htaccess rules?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set up a redirect from example.com/wordpress/* to your homepage by using your cPanel?

Comment: wordpress is installed in the root so i can't use a wildcard or it will redirect loop forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) and redirecting each page manually, thus leaving irrelevant pages to throw a 404 error. It's not what I wanted but in the end it's best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this plugin.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/)
It allows redirection of all URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to your htaccess file:

`redirect 301 / http://www.yoursiteurl.com/`

Replace "yoursiteurl" with your actual domain.