# One page wordpress template - redirect all pages to home

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been searching this for months. Is there a plugin to redirect all pages to home? Or should i just put redirect to page.php template file?

I only have one pager and i need to redirect all pages to home (not posts)

Thank you

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10199389/132873 and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/125341/3480

Answer (score 0):

Either your solution, or you can use `.htaccess` redirect rules, like:

```
Redirect /old-index.html http://www.mynewwebsite.com/foldername/new-index.html
```

or just simple PHP solution, like (you're able to redirect traffic by putting the following line at the very top of a PHP document, nothing can be above it):

```
<?php
   header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
   header( "http://www.mynewwebsite.com" );
?>
```

More about `.htaccess` file redirection [here](http://htaccessredirect.co.uk).

**EDIT:**

Place the code below in your `.htaccess` file.
This will direct everything from the old host to the root of the new host:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.old.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I have at the moment but lets say client page has 20-50 pages which I'd like to redirect to home and avoid from search indexing (not just meta) and I don't want to redirect posts, just the pages. Doing it by hand is not viable option since I cannot be doing this for clients all the time in case they add more content.

Comment: I tried that php to page.php template file which is loaded for every page as well
     <?php 
     header('Location: http://www.url.com');
     exit();
     ?> 
but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in functions.php

```
function redirect_page_standard() {
  is_page()
    and wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 )
    and exit;
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_page_standard' );
```

You could also redirect just a specific page-template when you replace `is_page()` with `is_page_template('mytemplate.php')`.